# MPI non-blocking communication and pthreads difference?

Tags: client-server, mpi, p2p

In MPI, there are non-blocking calls like `MPI_Isend` and `MPI_Irecv`.

If I am working on a p2p project, the Server would listen to many clients.

One way to do it:

```
for(int i = 1; i < highest_rank; i++){
    MPI_Irecv(....,i,....statuses[i]); //listening to all slaves
}
while(true){
   for( int i = 1; i < highest_rank; i++){
         checkStatus(statuses[i])
         if true do somthing
}
```

Another old way that I could do it is:

```
Server creating many POSIX threads, pass in a function, 
that function will call MPI_Recv and loop forever.
```

Theoretically, which one would perform faster on the server end? If there is another better way to write the server, please let me know as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter solution does not seem very efficient to me because of all the overhead from managing the pthreads inside a MPI process.

Anyway I would rewrite you MPI code as:

```
for(int i = 1; i < highest_rank; i++){
   MPI_Irev(....,i,....requests[i]); //listening to all slaves
}
while(true){
   MPI_waitany(highest_rank, request[i], index, status);
   //do something useful

}
```

Even better you can use MPI_Recv with MPI_ANY_SOURCE as the rank of the source of a message. It seems like your server does not have anything to do except serving request therefore there is no need to use an asynchronous recv.
Code would be:

```
while(true){
    MPI_Recv(... ,MPI_ANY_SOURCE, REQUEST_TAG,MPI_comm,status)
    //retrieve client id from status and do something
}
```

Comment: Q:If use MPI_ANY_SOURCE, would I be able to know which salve sent this request to me?

Comment: @LouisTan Yes, check this master-slave model which is built off of that principle http://www.lam-mpi.org/tutorials/one-step/ezstart.php

Comment: @pyCthon great tutorial, Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

When calling MPI_Irecv, it is NOT safe to test the recv buffer until AFTER MPI_Test* or MPI_Wait* have been called and successfully completed.  The behavior of directly testing the buffer without making those calls is implementation dependent (and ranges from not so bad to a segfault).

Setting up a 1:1 mapping with one MPI_Irecv for each remote rank can be made to work.  Depending on the amount of data that is being sent, and the lifespan of that data once received, this approach may consume an unacceptable amount of system resources.  Using MPI_Testany or MPI_Testall will likely provide the best balance between message processing and CPU load.  If there is no non-MPI processing that needs to be done while waiting on incoming messages, MPI_Waitany or MPI_Waitall may be preferable.

If there are outstanding MPI_Irecv calls, but the application has reached the end of normal processing, it is "necessary" to MPI_Cancel those outstanding calls.  Failing to do that may be caught in MPI_Finalize as an error.

A single MPI_Irecv (or just MPI_Recv, depending on how aggressive the message handling needs to be) on MPI_ANY_SOURCE also provides a reasonable solution.  This approach can also be useful if the amount of data received is "large" and can be safely discarded after processing.  Processing a single incoming buffer at a time can reduce the total system resources required, at the expense of serializing the processing.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just comment on your idea to use POSIX threads (or whatever other threading mechanism there might be). Making MPI calls from multiple threads at the same time requires that the MPI implementation is initialised with the highest level of thread support of `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE`:

```c
int provided;

MPI_Init_thread(&argv, &argc, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &provided);
if (provided != MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE)
{
    printf("Error: MPI does not provide full thread support!\n");
    MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
}
```

Although the option to support concurrent calls from different threads was introduced in the MPI standard quite some time ago, there are still MPI implementations that struggle to provide fully working multithreaded support. MPI is all about writing portable, at least in theory, applications, but in this case real life differs badly from theory. For example, one of the most widely used open-source MPI implementation - Open MPI - still does not support native InfiniBand communication (InfiniBand is the very fast low latency fabric, used in most HPC clusters nowadays) when initialised at `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` level and therefore switches to different, often much slower and with higher latency transports like TCP/IP over regular Ethernet or IP-over-InfiniBand. Also there are some supercomputer vendors, whose MPI implementations do not support `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` at all, often because of the way the hardware works.

Besides, `MPI_Recv` is a blocking call which poses problems with proper thread cancellation (if necessary). You have to make sure that all threads escape the infinite loop somehow, e.g. by having each worker send a termination message with the appropriate tag or by some other protocol.